# Differentiating between actual value and default(T) when using generics in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-3.0

I'm creating two custom collection called 
`BinarySearchTree<T>` and `DoublyLinkedList<T>`.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> : IBinarySearchTree<T>,IEnumerable<T>
{

    private DoublyLinkedList<T>[] innerCollection;
    private BinarySearchTreeEnumerator<T> bstEnumerator = new BinarySearchTreeEnumerator<T>();;

    public BinarySearchTree(T root)
    {
        innerCollection[0] = new DoublyLinkedList<T>(root, null, null);
    }
}

public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IDoublyLinkedList<T>
{
    private T currentItem;
    private T previousItem;
    private T nextItem;

    public DoublyLinkedList(T cItem,T pItem,T nItem)
    {
        currentItem = cItem;
        previousItem = pItem;
        nextItem = nItem;
    }

    #region IDoublyLinkedList<T> interface implementation

    public bool IsLeafNode(DoublyLinkedList<T> node)
    {
        if (node.previousItem != null && node.nextItem != null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In the constructor of `BinarySearchTree<T>` I'm initializing the root node of the binary search for which my `previousItem` and `nextItem` in `DoublyLinkedList<T>` are to be assinged to `null`.

```
public BinarySearchTree(T root)
    {
        innerCollection[0] = new DoublyLinkedList<T>(root, null, null);
    }
```

I understand that the Generics don't allow me to assign `null` since there can be value types involved. But if I assign `default(T)` to the  `previousItem` and `nextItem`, how will I differentiate between a user really providing `0` for a node in case of `BinarySearchTree<int>` ?

```
public BinarySearchTree(T root)
    {
        innerCollection[0] = new DoublyLinkedList<T>(root, default(T), default(T));
    }
```

This removes the compile time error, but I don't want `0` to be assigned to `previousItem` ,`currentItem` of the root node. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: In a linked list the next and previous should be a node not the actual values being stored.  Your `DoublelyLinkedList<T>` is basically a glorified `Tuple<T,T,T>`.  So instead of `public DoublyLinkedList(T cItem,T pItem,T nItem)` it should be `public DoublyLinkedList(T cItem,DoublyLinkedList<T> pNode,DoublyLinkedList<T> nNode)`

Comment: ... which solves your problem, because then the previous and next items are of a class type and can be assigned `null`.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't implement a linked list. It provides no mechanism to traverse the data structure, which is a critical feature of any linked data structure. See marked duplicate for details on how an _actual_ linked list is implemented; a doubly-linked list just has an extra reference, for the reverse linking direction. As noted in the previous comment, if you were to implement the list correctly, being able to distinguish a null link would be trivial.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why not use the existing [linked list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8)? It exists since .Net 2.0. Also the counterpart for the BinarySearchTree is the [SortedSet<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score -1):

There are bugs in your implementation. But to answer your specific question, you can restrict `T` to be a reference type, thus allowing `null` to be assigned.

On the other hand, if you fixed the bugs in your implementation the problem would go away:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IDoublyLinkedList<T>
{
    private T currentItem;
    private DoublyLinkedList<T> previousItem;
    private DoublyLinkedList<T> nextItem;

    public DoublyLinkedList(T cItem, DoublyLinkedList<T> pItem, DoublyLinkedList<T> nItem)
    {
        currentItem = cItem;
        previousItem = pItem;
        nextItem = nItem;
    }
```

That is, the previous/next items must be your wrapper class, and thus are always reference types and so can be `null`.